# Automapper + EF4 + ASP.NET MVC - getting 'context disposed' error (I know why, but how to fix it?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, closures, automapper

I have this really basic code in a MVC controller action. It maps an `Operation` model class to a very basic `OperationVM` view-model class .

```
public class OperationVM: Operation 
{
    public CategoryVM CategoryVM { get; set; }
}
```

I need to load the complete list of categories in order to create a CategoryVM instance.
Here's how I (try to) create a `List<OperationVM>` to show in the view.

```
public class OperationsController : Controller {

    private SomeContext context = new SomeContext ();

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var ops = context.Operations.Include("blah...").ToList();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Operation, OperationVM>()
            .ForMember(
                dest => dest.CategoryVM, 
                opt => opt.MapFrom(
                    src => CreateCatVM(src.Category, context.Categories)
                    //  trouble here ----------------^^^^^^^
                )
            );
        var opVMs = ops.Select(op => Mapper.Map<Operation, OperationVM>(op))
                       .ToList();

        return View(opVMs);
    }
}
```

All works great first time I hit the page. The problem is, the mapper object is static. So when calling `Mapper.CreateMap()`, the instance of the current `DbContext` is saved in the closure given to CreateMap().

The 2nd time I hit the page, the static map is already in place, still using the reference to the initial, now disposed, `DbContext`.

The exact error is:

```
The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.
```

The question is: How can I make AutoMapper always use the *current* context instead of the initial one?

Is there a way to use an "instance" of automapper instead of the static `Mapper` class? 
If this is possible, is it recommended to re-create the mapping every time? I'm worried about reflection slow-downs.

I read a bit about custom resolvers, but I get a similar problem - How do I get the custom resolver to use the current context?

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be a weakness with using EF with AutoMapper.  I've run into the same problem when trying to map a DTO back to an entity.  Hopefully you'll find the secret.  I was forced to make my own cludgy static method, and would love to be able to ditch it for a real solution.

Comment: Why you pass context.Categories. Try to iterate before pass it to automapper. use var categories = context.Categories.ToArray() and pass categories to CreateCatVM method.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov The call to `Mapper.CreateMap(...)` should really only be called once, e.g. from a static ctor, not each time I need to map objects. And the list of categories may well change in between.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible, but the setup is a bit complicated. I use this in my projects with help of Ninject for dependency injection.

AutoMapper has concept of TypeConverters. Converters provide a way to implement complex operations required to convert certain types in a separate class. If converting Category to CategoryVM requires a database lookup you can implement that logic in custom TypeConverter class similar to this:

```
using System;
using AutoMapper;

public class CategoryToCategoryVMConverter : 
        TypeConverter<Category, CategoryVM>
{
    public CategoryToCategoryVMConverter(DbContext context)
    {
        this.Context = context;
    }

    private DbContext Context { get; set; }

    protected override CategoryVM ConvertCore(Category source)
    {
        // use this.Context to lookup whatever you need
        return CreateCatVM(source, this.Context.Categories);
    }
}
```

You then to configure AutoMapper to use your converter:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Category, CategoryVM>().ConvertUsing<CategoryToCategoryVMConverter>();
```

Here comes the tricky part. AutoMapper will need to create a new instance of our converter every time you map values, and it will need to provide DbContext instance for constructor. In my projects I use Ninject for dependency injection, and it is configured to use the same instance of DbContext while processing a request. This way the same instance of DbContext is injected both in your controller and in your AutoMapper converter. The trivial Ninject configuration would look like this:

```
Bind<DbContext>().To<SomeContext>().InRequestScope();
```

You can of course use some sort of factory pattern to get instance of DbContext instead of injecting it in constructors.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Awesome answer. Can't wait to try it. Just one question: Can you share a link to documentation for AutoMapper's `InXXXScope()` methods? Can't seem to find any.

Comment: That's actually an Ninject method. http://www.ninject.org/ You can install ninject for MVC project through nuget, just search for ninject mvc.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a workaround that's not completely hacky.
Basically, I tell AutoMapper to ignore the tricky field and I update it myself.

The updated controller looks like this:

```
public class OperationsController : Controller {

    private SomeContext context = new SomeContext ();

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var ops = context.Operations.Include("blah...").ToList();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Operation, OperationVM>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CategoryVM, opt => opt.Ignore());

        var opVMs = ops.Select(
            op => {
                var opVM = Mapper.Map<Operation, OperationVM>(op);
                opVM.CategoryVM = CreateCatVM(op.Category, context.Categories);
                return opVM;
            })
            .ToList();

        return View(opVMs);
    }
}
```

Still curious how this could be done from within AutoMapper...

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @LeffeBrune is perfect. However, I want to have the same behavior, but I don't want to map every property myself. Basically I just wanted to override the "ConstructUsing".

Here is what I came up with.

```
public static class AutoMapperExtension
{
    public static void ConstructUsingService<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> mappingExression, Type typeConverterType)
    {
        mappingExression.ConstructUsing((ResolutionContext ctx) =>
        {
            var constructor = (IConstructorWithService<TSource, TDestination>)ctx.Options.ServiceCtor.Invoke(typeConverterType);
            return constructor.Construct((TSource)ctx.SourceValue);
        });
    }
}

public class CategoryToCategoryVMConstructor : IConstructorWithService<Category, CategoryVM>
{
    private DbContext dbContext;

    public DTOSiteToHBTISiteConverter(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public CategoryVM Construct(Category category)
    {
        // Some commands here
        if (category.Id > 0)
        {
            var vmCategory = dbContext.Categories.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == category.Id);
            if (vmCategory == null)
            {
                throw new NotAllowedException();
            }

            return vmCategory;
        }

        return new CategoryVM();
    }
}

// Initialization
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(type => nInjectKernelForInstance.Get(type));
    cfg.CreateMap<Category, CategoryVM>().ConstructUsingService(typeof(CategoryToCategoryVMConstructor));
};
```