# Create map with DBContext lookup, using automapper and ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ninject, automapper

So what I'm trying to do is use my DBContext to get some information from the DB for a mapping.

So I create a custom TypeConverter:

```
public class RoundVMtoTrampetRound : ITypeConverter<RoundVM, TrampetRound>
{

    public RoundVMtoTrampetRound(DBTariff context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    private DBTariff context { get; set; }

    public TrampetRound Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        RoundVM source = (RoundVM)context.SourceValue;
        Mapper.CreateMap<RoundVM, TrampetRound>();
        var dest = Mapper.Map<TrampetRound>(source);
        dest.Difficulty = this.context.DifficultyTrampet.Find(source.Id);
        return dest;
    }
}
```

And in my controller i create a mapper using:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<RoundVM, TrampetRound>().ConvertUsing<RoundVMtoTrampetRound>();
```

But when i do the mapping i get error message saying that there is no default constructor. But i want ninject to do this for me with the code:

```
kernel.Bind<DBTariff>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

An answer is here but i still get the same problem
[Automapper + EF4 + ASP.NET MVC - getting 'context disposed' error (I know why, but how to fix it?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751313/automapper-ef4-asp-net-mvc-getting-context-disposed-error-i-know-why-b/12323519#12323519)

I have tried the solution given in the link but get the same error.
So how to i get Automapper to use my Ninject to fix the problem?

**Edit**

I also found this where the same thing is done with autofac
http://thoai-nguyen.blogspot.se/2011/10/autofac-automapper-custom-converter-di.html
so my guess is that i need to tell automapper to use my ninject resolver but how to i do that and where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All information you need is given in the [blog article you already linked](http://thoai-nguyen.blogspot.se/2011/10/autofac-automapper-custom-converter-di.html).
To break it down into the absolute minimum information, you need to do:

```
Mapper.Initialize(x =>
{
     x.ConstructServicesUsing(type => kernel.Get(type));
});
```

before you ever access any other `Mapper.` property / method, so you need to call `Mapper.Initialize(..)` before you do `Mapper.CreateMap`.

Comment: Thanks, but where should i put this? In NinjectWebCommon or in each controller?

Comment: I'm not perfectly familiar with .net MVC stuff, but i'm quite certain that putting it into each controller will break "Initialize before Mapper.CreateMap`! Ideally you'd put it immediately after the `new StandardKernel()` statement. Now since that's probably handled by some ninject nuget package, you'll have to check what kind of extension points there are to `NinjectWebCommon`. You might try putting it into the overrride of `NinjectHttpApplication.CreateKernel()`

Comment: new StandardKernel() is in NinjectWebCommon and it works! Thank you!